# SSRS Report from View

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, sql-server-2000, reportingservices-2005, ssrs-2008-r2

An SSRS report has been created .The dataset has been defined on bases of a query.The query is

```
SELECT Organisation,
       SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR, dt_dt), 1, 11) AS Expr1,
       CNT
FROM   v_111_status
```

Every time I refresh the data in the view and run the ssrs report ,I can not see those changes reflected 
on the SSRS reports!

When i fire the above query in SSMS , I can see the changes!

*Is any of the dataset property has to be checked to get the data?*

Comment: A couple of questions - Are you viewing the report on BIDS or on the browser through report viewer? Does it happen for all reports or specifically for this report?

Comment: Which SSRS version are you using? you have 3 tagged in your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try opening the dataset properties in SSRS and clicking "Refresh Fields". If you made changes which created new fields etc... you won't see them until you click "Refresh Fields".

[image]

If the problem isn't that you adding new columns etc... you should try refreshing the report.
In the preview tab click the refresh button and see if that helps:

[image]

If you're still seeing an issue try to delete any files in the report project solution folder that have an extension of .rdl.data, this file holds details that caches/save the data of the last time you ran the report locally. It is not an important file and will do no harm when you delete it.

Comment: My data source is SQL SERVER 2000!

Comment: @user1254579 - what does your datasource being SQL Server 2000 have anything to do with my suggestions? All of these suggestions are implemented in SSRS and not in SQL Server.

Comment: but it still not working.working. Every time I have to create a new report to get the updated data.The previous report does not show the new data!

Comment: I'm all out of suggestions then. All of my suggestions that pertain to doing things in SSRS above should help with the issue you're seeing.

Comment: Why don't you test editing the query.  Try putting this in the dataset and see if you see the data in the union returned on the report Make sure to push "Refresh Fields": SELECT        Organisation, SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar, dt_dt), 1, 11) AS Expr1, CNT
FROM            v_111_status     
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Test1','Test1',999